# SQL query with distinct and group by snowflake

Tags: sql, group-by, distinct, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

What I'm trying to accomplish is to get all the records for a given MPN, however, I only want the latest `DeliveryDate` from  `shpm` but given the fact that  the  `MAX` function needs to be in the group by clause, It does not get the latest record, it gets all the records because of the distinct  `DeliveryDate`, it gets two records instead of one, how could I achieve this? This is in snowflake tho.

This is my SQL code

```
SELECT
    MD.MPN,
    MD.LOTCODE,
    MD.DATECODE,
    SHIP.ITEMCODE AS SYSTEMPARTNUMBER, 
    SHIP.SERIALNUMBER AS SYSTEMSERIALNUMBER, 
    SHIP.CUSTOMERNAME, 
    SHIP.SHIPTOADDRESS AS ADDRESS,
    SUM(IFNULL(SHIP.QUANTITY,0)) AS QUANTITY,
    SHIP.DELIVERYDATE
FROM cunits UNITS
   JOIN unc UC ON UC.CHILDUNITID = UNITS.ID
   JOIN shpm SHIP ON SHIP.SERIALNUMBER = UC.SYSSN
   JOIN tsern SN ON SN.UNITID = UNITS.ID
   JOIN machined MD ON MD.SERIALNUMBER = SN.SERIALNUMBER     
WHERE --SYSTEMSERIALNUMBER = '001801055469' and 
MPN = 'XC0402A105KP5CNN-S'
GROUP BY MD.MPN,MD.LOTCODE,MD.DATECODE,SHIP.ITEMCODE,SHIP.SERIALNUMBER,SHIP.CUSTOMERNAME,SHIP.SHIPTOADDRESS
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So guessing some data to match to SQL

```
WITH cunits AS (
    SELECT * from values (1) v(id)
), unc AS (
    SELECT * FROM VALUES (1,'123') v(CHILDUNITID,SYSSN)
), shpm AS (
    SELECT * FROM VALUES ('a', '123', 10, '2020-02-01'),
       ('a', '123', 20, '2020-01-01') 
   v(ITEMCODE, SERIALNUMBER, QUANTITY, DELIVERYDATE)
), tsern AS (
    SELECT * FROM VALUES (1,'zxc') v(UNITID,SERIALNUMBER)
), machined as (
    SELECT * FROM VALUES ('zxc', 'XC0402A105KP5CNN-S') v(SERIALNUMBER, MPN)
)
```

and dropping some columns that don't matter from the example

```
SELECT
    MD.MPN,
    SHIP.ITEMCODE AS SYSTEMPARTNUMBER, 
    SHIP.SERIALNUMBER AS SYSTEMSERIALNUMBER, 
    SUM(IFNULL(SHIP.QUANTITY,0)) AS QUANTITY,
    SHIP.DELIVERYDATE
FROM cunits UNITS
   JOIN unc UC ON UC.CHILDUNITID = UNITS.ID
   JOIN shpm SHIP ON SHIP.SERIALNUMBER = UC.SYSSN
   JOIN tsern SN ON SN.UNITID = UNITS.ID
   JOIN machined MD ON MD.SERIALNUMBER = SN.SERIALNUMBER     
WHERE 
MPN = 'XC0402A105KP5CNN-S'
GROUP BY MD.MPN,SHIP.ITEMCODE,SHIP.SERIALNUMBER;
```

now `SHIP.DELIVERYDATE` has to be added to the `group by` clause otherwise this code will never run, even ignoring your desire to not see the `2020-01-01` data

once you add that you get two rows which you don't want.

```
MPN SYSTEMPARTNUMBER    SYSTEMSERIALNUMBER  QUANTITY    DELIVERYDATE
XC0402A105KP5CNN-S  a   123 10  2020-02-01
XC0402A105KP5CNN-S  a   123 20  2020-01-01
```

Gordon's solution, to add a QUALIFY

```
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY MD.MPN, SHIP.SERIALNUMBER ORDER BY SHIP.DELIVERYDATE DESC) = 1;
```

correctly gives the answer, but calculating all the results and the pruning the ones not wanted latter.. where depending on your dataset size and how many rows are in your `shpm` table, a CTE to pre-filter might work better..

```
WITH cunits AS (
    SELECT * from values (1) v(id)
), unc AS (
    SELECT * FROM VALUES (1,'123') v(CHILDUNITID,SYSSN)
), shpm AS (
    SELECT * FROM VALUES ('a', '123', 10, '2020-02-01'),
       ('a', '123', 20, '2020-01-01') 
   v(ITEMCODE, SERIALNUMBER, QUANTITY, DELIVERYDATE)
), tsern AS (
    SELECT * FROM VALUES (1,'zxc') v(UNITID,SERIALNUMBER)
), machined as (
    SELECT * FROM VALUES ('zxc', 'XC0402A105KP5CNN-S') v(SERIALNUMBER, MPN)
), pre_filtered_shpm AS (
    select * from shpm
    QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SERIALNUMBER ORDER BY DELIVERYDATE DESC) = 1
)
SELECT
    MD.MPN,
    SHIP.ITEMCODE AS SYSTEMPARTNUMBER, 
    SHIP.SERIALNUMBER AS SYSTEMSERIALNUMBER, 
    SUM(IFNULL(SHIP.QUANTITY,0)) AS QUANTITY,
    SHIP.DELIVERYDATE
FROM cunits UNITS
   JOIN unc UC ON UC.CHILDUNITID = UNITS.ID
   JOIN pre_filtered_shpm SHIP ON SHIP.SERIALNUMBER = UC.SYSSN
   JOIN tsern SN ON SN.UNITID = UNITS.ID
   JOIN machined MD ON MD.SERIALNUMBER = SN.SERIALNUMBER     
WHERE 
MPN = 'XC0402A105KP5CNN-S'
GROUP BY MD.MPN,SHIP.ITEMCODE,SHIP.SERIALNUMBER,SHIP.DELIVERYDATE;
```

Comment: Whether done in a CTE or as a sub-select, running the QUALIFY before all of the joins is definitely more efficient.  This is actually a better answer than the one chosen as correct purely based on performance.

Comment: While the first answer was definetly right, this one vastly improves performance. Thank you very much for the ellaborate response

Comment: @MikeWalton . . . That is true if you can figure out where the duplicates are coming from.  I don't think there is enough information in the question to figure that out and this is a guess that happens to work -- still a good solution, but making assumptions about the data model that are not explained in the question.

Comment: The OP actually mentioned where the duplicates occur.  It's not a guess.

Comment: I was thinking that it's rather "potentially" worrying optimization, to Gordon's point, as number of linking tables could be 'where the dups come from" which really means the person writing the SQL really needs to know the data.. It's almost more "worrying that the data is good except sometimes it's "corrupted" lets filter it in the report"  anyways I shows one way to improve performance, but it's rather critical to understand the nature/shape of the data, to have correct results.

Answer (score 3):

Use `ROW_NUMBER()` and `QUALIFY`:

```
SELECT MD.MPN, MD.LOTCODE, MD.DATECODE,
       SHIP.ITEMCODE AS SYSTEMPARTNUMBER, SHIP.SERIALNUMBER AS SYSTEMSERIALNUMBER, 
       SHIP.CUSTOMERNAME, SHIP.SHIPTOADDRESS AS ADDRESS,
       SUM(COALESCE(SHIP.QUANTITY, 0)) AS QUANTITY,
       SHIP.DELIVERYDATE
FROM cunits UNITS JOIN
     unc UC
     ON UC.CHILDUNITID = UNITS.ID JOIN
     shpm SHIP
     ON SHIP.SERIALNUMBER = UC.SYSSN JOIN
     tsern SN
     ON SN.UNITID = UNITS.ID JOIN
     machined MD
     ON MD.SERIALNUMBER = SN.SERIALNUMBER     
WHERE '001801055469' and MPN = 'XC0402A105KP5CNN-S'
GROUP BY MD.MPN, MD.LOTCODE, MD.DATECODE, SHIP.ITEMCODE, SHIP.SERIALNUMBER, SHIP.CUSTOMERNAME, SHIP.SHIPTOADDRESS
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY MD.MPN, SHIP.SERIALNUMBER ORDER BY SHIP.SHIPDATE DESC) = 1;
```

This returns on row per `MPN`, which is how I interpret your question.  You may want other columns in the `PARTITION BY` as well.

Comment: I believe I didn't explain very good. The relationship is like this: One ```MPN``` has multiple serialnumbers attached to it, but the ```serialnumber``` has only one ```deliverydate``` (or it should)  however, sometimes a new record comes in with everything in the same way except the deliverydate which is greater than the last one that ```MPN``` and ```SerialNumber``` previously had and I only need the latest one. I hope this makes sense or if I'm being redundant because this is what you posted, let me know

Comment: @DiegoDuarte . . . It sounds like you want `SHIP.SERIALNUMBER` in the `PARTITION BY` as well.

Comment: @MikeWalton the alias is `SHIP`

Comment: @DiegoDuarte . . . Did this not do what you want?  I assumed when you accepted the answer that it is correct, and `qualify` seems like the simplest solution.

Comment: It did it, and it is the right answer but the performance from the other answer is better. it's just that. And it is the simplest solution, I'm just concerned on the db performance because there are over 650 million records in the machined table